# Configuring QT for Ubuntu Host & Ubuntu Target

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt5, cross-compiling

I've just started with QT and I am a beginner, I have done my research but I failed and found QT very complex. I am requesting experts on this forum to please please help me out.

#### My goal

To cross compile a project made with QT (which someone else has built) that contains a `.pro` file which references a few `.cpp` and `.h` files in the project folder. Let's assume this project is a simple hello world project.
After configuring QT, I assume I have to do this to generate makefile and compile this project using qmake, in the end get a binary of the project.

```
qmake –o Makefile myProject.pro
make
```

I am configuring Qt on a Host with `4.14.13-perform x86_64 GNU/Linux`
to cross compile a project build for Target with `4.14.13+ x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Note :- We usually build this project for Raspberry Pi Target. But this time, I've to build this for Ubuntu Target which I am finding difficult.

#### What did I do

1. I downloaded QT tar from `http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.14/5.14.2/single/` and untar-ed it.
2. I have `home/uname/qt-everywhere-src-5.14.2` folder
3. In this step I am facing issues in configuring QT environment for **Ubuntu Host** to build a project on my **Ubuntu Target**.
4. compile QT
   `make`
5. configure qmake
   `/opt/Qt5.14.2/bin/qmake`

#### My doubts

1. I assume the next step is to configure QT on my Host System, but I am not sure what options should I pass. (assuming its a simple hello world project)
   `./configure -v .....{options}.....` be?
2. For different platforms, there are different compilers to be used, which are at `~/qt-everywhere-src-5.14.2/qtbase/mkspecs/devices` path.
   Eg. For raspberry Pi I have to use `linux-rasp-pi-g++` compiler.
   So for ubuntu target, the only compiler I could find relatable in the list was `linux-generic-g++`
   Is that the correct compiler to be used?

Thanks a lot everyone, in advance.
Looking forward to get some help.